# HTML-formatted selected text returns whitespace from a range selection

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript routine that retrieves the selection text by a user formatted as HTML:

```
function getHTMLOfSelection() {
    var range;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        return range.htmlText;
    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
            return div.innerHTML;
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

With the fiddle, make sure and select the quoted text first:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Y4BBq/13/

The code works fine, however, the selection includes a `\r\n` after every `</p>` and `<br/>`.
Why are these added and at what point? It seems redundant, as the `<p>` and `<br>` tags already include the new line.

Comment: Oop, nevermind; your fiddle works. I didn't realize you have to select the text first.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Because `http://jsfiddle.net/Y4BBq/13/` 404s.

Comment: @Rocket - Nevermind, stupid jsFiddle appended my username onto the link and I didn't notice. Fixed.

Comment: Jackson, I think you mean *interprets* the selection as having whitespace which is represented by HTML elements in the browser (although technically, they're DOM elements by then), *includes*. Right?

Comment: You're saying that `\r\n` - line breaks - are "redundant"? So you wanted to read all the returned HTML in a single line of code? You know that `\r\n` is Windows' default way to represent line breaks, and that your document - from which you're getting the selection - does have line breaks, right? When inserted in your `textarea`, the `\r\n` characters are correctly rendered as line breaks, meaning it displays exactly the document selection which you've got. I don't see where's your problem.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Indeed this is how they are represented internally. However, for my purposes, if a new line char represents in code what is rendered by a <p> (which it often does), I really have no use for the new line (ergo redundant). So, yes, the HTML in a single line would be great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's comment, if you want to return the HTML without line breaks, you can just use a regex to globally replace the `Carriage Return` (`\n`) and `Line Feed` (`\r`) characters by empty strings:

```
//apply this to remove line breaks from your strings, where str is the string
str = str.replace(/\n|\r/g, '');
//or directly in the return inside of your functions:
return range.htmlText.replace(/\n|\r/g, '');
return div.innerHTML.replace(/\n|\r/g, '');
```

This will remove all line breaks, beware that the HTML will lose readability if you select a long part of document.

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Y4BBq/22/)